# CLVisit behaving differently since iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, core-location

I have been working with CLVisits, and since the 11.3 update, a lot more Visit events are being generated which have no `arrivalDate` field. Normally, a first Visit event will be generated just with `arrivalDate` followed by a second one with both `arrivalDate` and `departureDate` (`arrivalDate` being the same as the previous event).
Essentially, these second ones are missing very frequently now following 11.3.

Has anyone else noticed this change of behaviour and would know how to explain it?

I also don't know why they were happening in the first place, if anyone has an answer to that it would be great.

Comment: Also posted this on the apple developper forums, might get an answer there too: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/308269#308269